# randomColor( ) function is not producing random colors

Tags: html, easeljs

While doing this lab I realized that the randomColor function was only producing black for the fill of the squares being rendered. 
Can anyone explain to me where my error is and possible fixes for it?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Recipe: Drawing a square</title>
        <script src="easel.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var canvas;
            var stage;
            var squareSide = 70;
            var squareOutline = 5;
            var max_rgb_color_value = 255;
            var gray = createjs.Graphics.getRGB(20, 20, 20);
            function init() {
                var rows = 5;
                var columns = 6;
                var squarePadding = 10;
                canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
                stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
                for(var i=0;i<rows*columns;i++){
                    var square = drawSquare();
                    square.x = (squareSide+squarePadding) * (i%columns);
                    square.y = (squareSide+squarePadding) * Math.floor(i/columns);
                    stage.addChild(square);
                    stage.update();
                }               
            }
            function drawSquare() {
                var shape = new createjs.Shape();
                var graphics = shape.graphics;
                var color = randomColor();
                graphics.setStrokeStyle(squareOutline);
                graphics.beginStroke(gray);
                graphics.beginFill(color);
                graphics.rect(squareOutline, squareOutline, squareSide, squareSide);                
                return shape;
            }       
            function randomColor(){
                var color = Math.floor(Math.random()*createjs.max_rgb_color_number);
                var color2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*createjs.max_rgb_color_number);
                var color3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*createjs.max_rgb_color_number);
                return createjs.Graphics.getRGB(color, color2, color3);
            }
        </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="960" height="600"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please tell me the complete easel.js script (server path) to test?

Answer (score 0):

I have every CreateJS build we have released, and as far as I can tell, there never was a `max_rgb_color_number`. I don't know where you got that in your example.

You can just substitute that variable with 255 (or 0xFF). Each channel in an RGB color is 0-255.

Another easy way to get a random RGB color is

```
var color = "#" + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF | 0).toString(16);
```

Cheers.

Comment: Happy to help :)